# How to access keys of javascript objects dynamically in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface IObj { 
    fname: string;
    lname: string;
}

const obj: IObj = <IObj>{};

const array: string[] = ['fname', 'lname'];

array.forEach((key: string, index: number) => {
    obj[key] = `${index}`; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IObj'.
});
```

I want to access object keys dynamically. But typescript is not letting me do it.
Is there any way to achieve is in typescript.

Comment: Curse it, god darn typescript not letting you do it.

Comment: @Spangle tried cursing it, didn't fix my problem ;) Any other solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared `array` as type `string[]`, and `key` as type `string`. If you want Typescript to know these strings are actually keys of `IObj`, then tell it that:

```js
const array: (keyof IObj)[] = ['fname', 'lname'];

array.forEach((key: keyof IObj, index: number) => {
    obj[key] = `${index}`;
});
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHkBGArZBvZAKGRORhDgFsIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0gGwurseYh2hAL6FCCAPYhGySTjoYcyALzIAPEuwA+PCI4TpsuFChwAnnQAUAawjnJMNFmwBKANoBdVcncBycioIPwAaZD8eIL9PAxMzcwA6GEkoAFFEAAsrW3s6OwcnLTDQABMIAA86EABXSkxoV1VtfE4SeWx3fO81AAMAEjxSipEejhFXDiA)

Comment: There's no need to specify types in the forEach callback if you don't want to, TS can infer them just fine

Comment: Yes, indeed; I was just directly adapting the code to change `string` to the more specific type.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the quick response. Just one more question, Suppose I have one more object  obj2 and I want to assign its value to obj. How should I proceed.